# An error occured while mapping an array of objects in react - Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (13:9)eslint

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to map a array of object of data and it ended up in some error I can't figureout what was the issue with the code. kindly ignore the console.logs I am having it for my references

[image: screenshot of error]

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { questionContext } from "../pages/App";

const Display = () => {
  const { list } = useContext(questionContext);

  const upVote = () => {
    console.log(list);
  };
  
  const downVote = () => {
    console.log(list);
  };

  return (

    {list.map((items,index) => {
      return(
        <div className="Display">
          <p>{items.votes}</p>
          <button onClick={upVote}></button>
          <button onClick={downVote}></button>
    
          <p>{items}</p>
          <textarea></textarea>
          <button>SUBMIT</button>
    
          <button>BookMark</button>
    
          <p>Time</p>
        </div>

      )
    })}

  );
};

export default Display;
```

Comment: You have a syntax error. You cannot output JSX dynamic sections without any JSX elements. Either wrap the `{list.map(...)}` in an element / fragment or remove the braces and use `return list.map(...)`

Comment: It seems the code is the minimal reproducible example. Even without knowledge of the syntax of JSX, it seems you are defining an object with `{` while no field was declared. Either remove the `{` or add a field name.

Comment: This can be closed as a **typo**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This was an typo error it can be solved by enclosing the jsx elements inside fragments or div